# Table is marked as crashed and should be repaired

Tags: mysql, myisam

Периодически, где-то раз в неделю, отваливается mysql. В логах пишет, что крашутся некоторые таблицы.
В большинстве случаев все само лечится, но хочется понять, где искать источник проблемы, чтобы исключать временные сбои ?

Comment: таблицы сами не крашаться. они крашаться от того, что падает MySQL, а падает он по какой то другой причине. А что до таблиц, их возможно стоит переделать в InnoDB, ибо крашуться только MyISAM таблицы

Comment: а где смотреть, почему падает мускул ?

Comment: надо внимательнее посмотреть логи самого mysql. Если никаких сообщений, типа что он собрался завершаться нет, то смотреть системный лог (/var/log/messages например, в разных системах по разному) примерно в это время. Что то мне подсказывает, что вы там увидите сообщения OOM killer'а о том что он прибил процесс из за недостатка памяти в системе